# Changing data types after interpolating

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation

```
from tnorma import tnorma
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tnorma import tnorma

df6  = pd.read_csv('Static06_new.csv')
Z =tnorma(df6)
df = pd.DataFrame(Z)
print(df)
```

This is a simple enough code. The interpolation code "tnorma" is given here https://pypi.org/project/tnorma/

The Static06_new.csv files contains positional data with time column. The time column is not continuous, hence I am interpolating them.

The interpolation is successful, however, I am unable to convert the result back into a data-frame for further analysis.

The error received when running my code is as follows:

VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify `'dtype=object'` when creating the ndarray

```
   values = np.array([convert(v) for v in values])
                                                   0
0  [[109.00000000000001, 0.009174311926606001, 35...
1  [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, ...
2                                          [0, 3694]
```

Not sure how to proceed. Ideal case I would like it back in a data-frame format and save it as .csv file.

Kind regards,